# Masking using regular expressions for below format

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to mask the below string. Example below.

Input

```
A1../D//FASDFAS--DFASD//.F
```

Output (Skip first five and last two Alphanumeric's)

```
A1../D//FA***********D//.F
```

I am trying using below regex
([A-Za-z0-9]{5})(.*)(.{2})

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your efforts

Comment: "([A-Za-z0-9]{5})(.*)(.{2}) " i am using this regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that with a single regex you may use

```
text = text.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^|(?:[0-9A-Za-z][^0-9A-Za-z]*){2}$)|^(?:[^0-9A-Za-z]*[0-9A-Za-z]){5}).", "$1*");
```

Or, using the POSIX character class `Alnum`:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^|(?:\\p{Alnum}\\P{Alnum}*){2}$)|^(?:\\P{Alnum}*\\p{Alnum}){5}).", "$1*");
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/bMboTX) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2bGYw7/1/). If you plan to replace any code point rather than a single code unit with an asterisk,  replace `.` with `\P{M}\p{M}*+` (`"\\P{M}\\p{M}*+"`).

To make `.` match line break chars, add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern.

**Details**

- `(\G(?!^|(?:[0-9A-Za-z][^0-9A-Za-z]*){2}$)|^(?:[^0-9A-Za-z]*[0-9A-Za-z]){5})` -

  - `\G(?!^|(?:[0-9A-Za-z][^0-9A-Za-z]*){2}$)` - a location after the successful match that is not followed with 2 occurrences of an alphanumeric char followed with 0 or more chars other than alphanumeric chars
  - `|` - or
  - `^(?:[^0-9A-Za-z]*[0-9A-Za-z]){5}` -  start of string, followed with five occurrences of 0 or more non-alphanumeric chars followed with an alphanumeric char
- `.` - any code unit other than line break characters (if you use `\P{M}\p{M}*+` - any code point).

Answer (score 2):

You solve your issue by using `Pattern` and `Matcher` with a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Efpea6/1) which match multiple groups :

```
String str = "A1../D//FASDFAS--DFASD//.F";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?\\/\\/..)(.*?)(.\\/\\/.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    str = matcher.group(1)
            + matcher.group(2).replaceAll(".", "*")
            + matcher.group(3);
}
```

**Detail**

- `(.*?\\/\\/..)` first group to match every thing until `//`
- `(.*?)` second group to match every thing between group one and three
- `(.\\/\\/.*)` third group to match every thing after the last character before the `//` until the end of string

**Outputs**

```
A1../D//FA***********D//.F
```

I think this solution is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, masking of characters in the middle of a string can be done using negative lookbehind `(?<!)` and positive lookahead groups `(?=)`.
But in this case lookbehind group can't be used because it does not have an obvious maximum length due to unpredictable number of non-alphanumeric characters between first five alphanumeric characters (`.` and `/` in the `A1../D//FA`).

A `substring` method can used as a workaround for inability to use negative lookbehind group:

```
String str = "A1../D//FASDFAS--DFASD//.F";
int start = str.replaceAll("^((?:\\W{0,}\\w{1}){5}).*", "$1").length();
String maskedStr = str.substring(0, start) +
    str.substring(start).replaceAll(".(?=(?:\\W{0,}\\w{1}){2})", "*");
System.out.println(maskedStr);
// A1../D//FA***********D//.F
```

But the most straightforward way is to use `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `java.util.regex.Matcher`:

```
String str = "A1../D//FASDFAS--DFASD//.F";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((?:\\W{0,}\\w{1}){5})(.+)((?:\\W{0,}\\w{1}){2})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
  String maskedStr = matcher.group(1) +
      "*".repeat(matcher.group(2).length()) +
      matcher.group(3);
  System.out.println(maskedStr); 
  // A1../D//FA***********D//.F
}
```

- `\W{0,}` - 0 or more non-alphanumeric characters
- `\w{1}` - exactly 1 alphanumeric character
- `(\W{0,}\w{1}){5}` - 5 alphanumeric characters and any number of alphanumeric characters in between
- `(?:\W{0,}\w{1}){5}` - do not capture as a group
- `^((?:\\W{0,}\\w{1}){5})(.+)((?:\\W{0,}\\w{1}){2})$` - substring with first five alphanumeric characters (group 1), everything else (group 2), substring with last 2 alphanumeric characters (group 3)